# Incorrect ExecutingAssembly being used

Tags: c#, resources

I have a utilities library (dll) which contains the class (shown below) for working with embedded resources. In Visual Studio 2013 it works as expected and loads the resources from the assembly which calls the function in the utilities library.

In Visual Studio 2015 when I call the functions the code attempts to load the resources from the utilities library instead of the calling library. They are seperate assemblies.

Please can you help me understand why this is happening, and how I can get it to work in Visual Studio 2015?
Thanks in advance.

```
public static class EmbeddedResources
{
    public static string[] GetAllResourceNames()
    {
        Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return _assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    }

    public static string ReadQueryResource(string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly _assembly;
        StreamReader _textStreamReader;
        try
        {
            _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));
            if (_textStreamReader.Peek() != -1)
                return _textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate this - you shouldn't need to read any resource names: just print out the executing assembly.

Comment: But it's not clear that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` *should* return the application assembly here. Perhaps you want `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` instead?

Comment: GetCallingAssembly (from the answer below) did the trick!

Comment: That's fine if you're sure it's never going to be called from a *different* library - or indeed from another method within the same library. But if you really want "the application assembly" then `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

> Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.

Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()

> Returns the Assembly of the method that invoked the currently executing method.

Comment: Thanks very much. Problem solved. I would still really like to know why this worked when running the app under Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Were you running under debugger? Have you checked project settings?